# Web application serves a DLL after setting up MVC 3 application in-side Sharepoint 2007 using IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sharepoint, iis-7, web-config

I am currently working on an sharepoint 2007, web application and I am trying to create an MVC 3 site inside the same website which runs on .Net Framework 4.0 (Integrated Mode).

Initially we had issues to get it working as web.config (for the main site[Sharepoint 2007]) had dlls registered for .net framework 2.0, even for the MVC 3 application. We got this problem resolved by updating the web.config in the .Net Framework, so right versions on dlls where registered for .Net 2.0 and 4.0.

The problem was solved and I was able to get to the MVC and main site without any issues, now all of a sudden, after restarting my VM, when I visit my the main site, a DLL is served (yes, browser downloads a dll file !!).

This is the case with 3 other colleagues of mine. Any expert advice would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uff ! After a days of staring at IIS and extensive googling, it turns out giving 'Execute' permission to handler mapping for _vti_bin folder resolves the problem. I am surprised no one had this issue before, or may be it could be something to do with out rake script (deployment package- script).

Anyways thanks to all those who viewed my question. Hope this answer helps someone !